# Cassandra: Inserting column in cassandra table

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I am trying to insert new column in Cassandra table. 
**Column Name**- feedback_map
Column type-  map of text, feedback_map

And trying to execute this statement.

```
      ALTER TABLE my_table ADD feedback_map map<text, frozen<feedback_details>>;
```

but getting unknown type error on feedback_details
Am pretty new to cassandra.

I am having custom feedback_details user type with two field-

```
       @Field(name = "field_mappings")
       private Map<String, String> fieldMappings;


       @Field(name = "field_defaults")
       private Map<String, String> fieldDefaults;
```

No i have not defined it yet? do i need to add this user type to my table first??

Comment: Have you defined your UDT yet?  What is the output of `desc type feedback_details;`?

Comment: I have updated my post Sir, please take a look

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure that your User Defined Type (UDT) exists.  If not, you'll need to create it:

```
CREATE TYPE feedback_details (
    field_mappings MAP<TEXT, TEXT>,
    field_defaults MAP<TEXT, TEXT>);
```

Then you'll be able to add it as a column on your table (as you have above):

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD feedback_map map<text, frozen<feedback_details>>;
```

Comment: Aah.. i was just going through the datastax documents. Thank you very much Sir